# Function call doesn't seem to pass variable

Tags: php

OK, so I have a function that generates prev/next links based on the page ID, and it was working before, but now it's not. All necessary variables used in the switch statement are defined before the functions that call them. Here's the function to generate the links:

```
function generateNavbar(){
//Name and number
$name = preg_replace("#[\d]#", "", strval($_GET["id"]));
$num = preg_replace("#[^\d]#", "", strval($_GET["id"]));

$maxNum = getMaxPage($name);

//Print the nav links
echo "<br><br><center><b>";
if(intval($num) > 1) echo "<a href=\"?id=" . $name . (intval($num) - 1) . "\"><< PREV</a>";
if(intval($num) > 1 && intval($num) < intval($maxNum)) echo " | ";
if(intval($num) < intval($maxNum)) echo "<a href=\"?id=" . $name . (intval($num) + 1) . "\">NEXT >></a>";
echo "</b></center>";
};
```

And here's the function to get the maximum value:

```
function getMaxPage($name){
//Get max value
switch($name){
    case "codeSquirrel":
        return $numSquirrel;
        break;
    case "strPhobia":
        return $numPhobia;
        break;
    case "strDouble":
        return $numDouble;
        break;
    default:
        return 0;
        break;
    };
};
```

The code for `getMaxPage()` was originally inside `generateNavbar`, but when I needed to use that same code in other functions that use the page number, it stopped working. It's like for some reason, the functions don't want to send `$name` to it, so it always returns 0. `getMaxPage()` is defined before all functions that call it, too. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If it's returning 0, then `$name` is neither of your switch cases.

Comment: Since we have no idea what `$_GET['id']` contains it's quite hard to tell. Most likely it does not include `codeSquirrel`, `strPhobia` or `strDouble` if you remove all numbers.

Comment: ..also, **your code is open to XSS injection - NEVER trust user input!**. To just accept `$_GET['id']` and output it in HTML means that people can put whatever HTML (or javascript) in there and have it execute for other users clicking on the link. Encode the HTML.

Comment: @h2ooooooo It is included; as I've mentioned, the code worked before. It stopped working when I split the functions.

Comment: @KelvinShadewing Have you tried to actually use `var_dump($name)` or do you still keep insisting that we guess the value of `$_GET['id']`?

Comment: @h2ooooooo And I already have code in place to prevent users from inputting invalid data. The code can only retrieve from one directory, and it filters out invalid characters.

Comment: @h2ooooooo You never mentioned `var_dump()` so why would I think to use it? The id is the name I'm passing followed by the number, so when clicking a link that says "?id=codeSquirrel3", it goes to the third page of my Squirrel guide. I know that part is working fine; it's passing the variable down that is the issue here. Please stay on topic, and if you need additional information, try asking politely and not getting snippy.

Comment: I stick to what I've said: `var_dump($name)` before `getMaxPage` call. Your var isn't passing the value you expect. The nesting [is good to go](https://eval.in/445252)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably not that no `$name` is passed to `getMaxPage`, but rather that `numSquirrel` *etc* is not defined within `getMaxPage`.
If these variables are defined within `generateNavBar` it explains why the code worked before the refactoring that made `getMaxPage` into a separate function.

Comment: They're defined at the global level. Though, since that same switch statement is what's being used by every function that uses them, I guess I could just put the values themselves there. I only defined them at the top to make them easier to find. I guess if I need to access them directly, I can just use gMP like any other get function, eh? I'll try that and get back to you after.